# Place image behind divs using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup (Fiddle Example Here: http://jsfiddle.net/9gvj11o5/8/)

```
<div class="header">           
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/2200x800" alt=""/>
  </div>    
  <div class="menu">This is the menu</div>    
  <div class="tools">These are the tools</div>        
</div>    
<div class="content">content</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.header {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  outline: 0;
}
```

I need the image to be responsive and have 100% width aligned to top.

But I also need the menu and tools to be over the image and having their normal flow.

Content should be after the image, so after the header.

The image would be the "background" of the header div. (I cannot use background-image)

I am using position but the menu and tools disappear the moment I use it.

What am I missing? Do I need another wrapper div somewhere?

Comment: why can't you use background-image in CSS?

Comment: @andi because this will be a slide show and images will be taken from a database so i do not know the images urls in my CSS

Comment: @MDMoura FYI you can use inline styles to do this, like `<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo( $database_var ); ?>);">[...]</div>`

Comment: yeah, I was thinking inline styles too if needed.

Comment: I am not sure I get all the solution you mention ... If I would like to make it a slide that would not slide the content to? I mean the tools and menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the 2 divs `.menu` & `.tools` so you need only to apply `z-index` to the wrapper `div` instead of each child. which make  `.menu` & `.tools` (wrapped) in front of the `.image`.

then change `position:absolute` to `position:relative` to `.image` in order to have `.content` below `header`.

Below you can see the snippet, very lightweight.

```css
.header {
    position: relative;
}
.image {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1
}
#menu-all {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:2
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/2200x800" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="menu-all">
        <div class="menu">This is the menu</div>
        <div class="tools">These are the tools</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

Comment: I like this approach ... But I would always need to control the content so that it would not get out of the image ...

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you mean (I'm not native  English), can you please explain in another words?

Comment: I mean, if the content in menu-all becomes higher than the image then it will fall outside of the image.

Comment: I know what you mean.. but if you are asking for a responsive image, it is really hard to have your menu & tools not overflowing the image unless you use small texts.

Comment: Yes ... Usually what I do is to hide a few elements as screen becomes smaller. I was just trying to figure if someone would have a better idea. Thank you for the code.

Comment: You can always use @media queries..for that purpose I guess this is what you are mentioning in the comment.. right?

Comment: Yes, basically I am trying to replicate what happens in www.airbnb.com where they have menu and search over image and the image is also cropped up and right when the browser resizes, yet the height seems to be constant.

Comment: height fixed and non-responsive.. so 2 different things ;)

Comment: Yes, height is fixed ... But by cropping the image it is still adaptable ... In fact I was looking for a mix of the two. The image would resize but in extreme cases, using media queries, it would start to crop ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `z-index` to define the layer order of your elements. The smaller the number, the closer to the "bottom" of the stack. So we give the img a very small number, and menu and tools a very large one.

```
.header {
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1; /* here you can use -1 as Paulie_D points out in the comments */
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    outline: 0;
    z-index: 2; /* here you can use -1 as Paulie_D points out in the comments */
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 888; /* You can remove this declaration entirely if you set -1 above */
}

.tools {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 888; /* You can remove this declaration entirely if you set -1 above */
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks for this! is `-1` widely supported? I had not seen that before

Comment: Comment deleted but yes, no issues whatsoever. Quite common in fact it's a CSS2 property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: In that case Tools will become over Menu. I can of course change the top value of tools ... But that is why in my original question asked that tools and menu would have their normal flow.